# Win CE7, ATL, Colbibri SDK, VS2008,

Tags: c++, atl

I am working on a cross-platform ATL project using the Visual Studio 2008 Professional IDE.

To be able to run the program on a Windows CE7 OS i am currently using "Colibri_SDK_WINCE7" SDK.

If i try to compile on Win CE7 some errors of the same type occur:

**errorC2668: ambiguous call to overloaded function**

Details:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlbase.h(7362) : error C2668: 'ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID': Mehrdeutiger Aufruf einer überladenen
>   Funktion
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlosapice.h(1313): kann 'int ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)' sein
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE
>   Tools\SDKs\SDK2wince7\include\ARMv4I\guiddef.h(138): oder "int
>   InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)" [bei argumentbezogenem
>   Lookup gefunden] bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(const CLSID, const
>   CLSID)'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(3916) : error C2668: 'ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID': Mehrdeutiger Aufruf einer
>   überladenenFunktion
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlosapice.h(1313): kann 'int ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)' sein
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE
>   Tools\SDKs\SDK2wince7\include\ARMv4I\guiddef.h(138): oder "int
>   InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)" [bei
>   argumentbezogenemLookup gefunden] bei Anpassung der Argumentliste
>   '(GUID, const GUID)'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(3933) : error C2668: 'ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID': Mehrdeutiger Aufruf einer überladenen
>   Funktion
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlosapice.h(1313): kann 'int ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)' sein
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE
>   Tools\SDKs\SDK2wince7\include\ARMv4I\guiddef.h(138): oder "int
>   InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)" [bei argumentbezogenem
>   Lookup gefunden] bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(const GUID, const
>   IID)'
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(3933) : error C2668: 'ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID': Mehrdeutiger Aufruf einer überladenen
>   Funktion
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlosapice.h(1313): kann 'int ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)' sein
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE
>   Tools\SDKs\SDK2wince7\include\ARMv4I\guiddef.h(138): oder "int
>   InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID [bei argumentbezogenem
>   Lookup gefunden]
>
> bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(const GUID, const IID)' C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlcom.h(3965) : error C2668: 'ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID': Mehrdeutiger Aufruf einer
>   überladenenFunktion
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlosapice.h(1313): kann 'int ATL::InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)' sein
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows CE
>   Tools\SDKs\SDK2wince7\include\ARMv4I\guiddef.h(138): oder "int
>   InlineIsEqualGUID(const GUID &,const GUID &)" [bei argumentbezogenem
>   Lookup gefunden] bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(GUID, const GUID)'

There seems to be some problem with the qualification of the namespace-name.

I tried to fix the issue by

```
using namespace ATL;
```

But neither with nor without using the namespace the error occurs.

Because the error occurs inside of some standart atl header, i cannot use the fully qualified expresion for the function-call.

```
ATL::someMethod();
```

Unfortunately i don't know which part of my own code invokes the critical ATL methods.

**Thanks in advance to all responses.**